# python-selenium \\ converting webelement.text to float

Tags: python, selenium

I have extracted a text containing a float from a website using selenium module. printing the number as text works, but converting it to float doesn't work, and i cant figure out why. here`s my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://beta.windguru.cz/station/468")
ellist=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("wgs_wind_avg_value")
for el in ellist:
    value = float(el.text)
    print(value)
browser.quit()
```

thank you for  the help!

Comment: Try `el.text.strip()`

Comment: It works fine on my system.

Comment: first of all- thank you, it worked! secondly- i thought iv'e already tried this, apparently i tried something else. weird. thanks again.

Comment: What was the issue.

Comment: it works as a print statement, but raises  an error when i try to assign it to a variable: print float(el.text.strip()) works, but wind=float(el.text.strip()) doesnt. (raises error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: )

Comment: What error does it raise?

Comment: i updated my last comment

Comment: Which version of python are you using and what's the exact output of `print float(el.text.strip()) `

Comment: python 2.7, and it went back to not working, without me changing the code. i cant figure out what is happening!

Comment: this doesnt work for me anymore: `value = float(el.text.strip())
    print(value)`: and raises the same error i mentioned before

Comment: after a little more debugging i found out that the error rose when el.text was None. the element text came empty quit randomly from the site- one time it came with content, and the other time it came empty. i tried to figure out why, and i suspected problems with the loading of the page. i put a `time.sleep(1)` to let it load a bit more before extracting content from the webpage, and it seemed to have done the job. any better solution?